# Is there another name for "emergency fix" that doesn't convey a sense of panic

Tags: release-management

"Emergency fix" is a fairly commonly used term. I've seen this used as an excuse to skip important development or testing steps though, because it's an "emergency". The word "emergency" seems to convey some degree of panic and thoughtlessness that isn't good.

Is there another term that people use to describe a change that should happen promptly, sooner than the next scheduled release, but may not even be that serious (maybe even just for 1 customer - certainly not an emergency)?

Comment: We usually use the term Hotfix, something that should be deployed to production. The Product Owner decides the priority.

Comment: Priority Update

Comment: Off-cycle release. [Example found on the internet](http://www.abiscorp.com/faq/index.php?title=Off-Cycle_Release_Procedures)

Answer (score 6):

"Hotfix", "Unscheduled Release" etc

However, you would be best advised I think to simply drop the "emergency" and sort out why you cant follow all the normal release steps. After all skipping checks is probably what caused the emergency in the first place.